# How to convert list of tuple (tf.constant, tf.constant) as tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, dataset

I'm trying to create a Transformer Model, I have 2 `np.arrays`, both have strings, I used them to create a list of tuples

The format of the tuple is :

```
class 'tuple' (tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'abc', tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'xyz')
```

I want to combine these tuples to form `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._OptionsDataset`, how can I do that?

Or is there any other way I could do it?

New to this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tensor_from_slices`. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices).

**EDIT**

```
Example
# Two tensors can be combined into one Dataset object. 
values1 = tf.constant(['A', 'B', 'A']) # ==> 3x1 tensor
values2 = tf.constant(['A', 'B', 'A']) # ==> 3x1 tensor
dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((values1, values2))
```

Comment: Would be nice if you'd sure an example of how you use that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948631/how-to-create-a-tensorflow-input-pipeline-for-local-dataset-available-as-json @U10-Forward. See this one